# JSP get object attribute by variable

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have JSP which contains "detail" object, which is serializable.

I need to output it's attributes based on List of values to be shown.

```
<c:forEach var="field" items="${detail.fieldsToShow}" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="value" value="detail.${field}"></c:set>
    <div class="mobileTemplateContainer noBorderTopOnly">
        <div class="mobileTemplateRightContainer">
            <p class="reviewLabel blackLabel noMarginBottom">
                <c:out value="${value}"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class="reviewLabel noMarginBottom">
            <fmt:message key="accountNumber" />
        </p>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

This code just outputs detail.fieldname, instead of values of those fields. I need to output values, not names.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
<c:forEach var="field" items="${detail.fieldsToShow}" varStatus="status">
<div class="mobileTemplateContainer noBorderTopOnly">
    <div class="mobileTemplateRightContainer">
        <p class="reviewLabel blackLabel noMarginBottom">
            <c:out value="${field.getName()}"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p class="reviewLabel noMarginBottom">
        <fmt:message key="accountNumber" />
    </p>
</div>
```